# Is Gohan Beast a super saiyan transformation, or can anyone get it?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

Gohan's last transformation changes his color, but so do other transformations, which arent saiyan-only transformations, such as Ultra Instinct or Ultra Ego. So,

Is Gohan Beast a super saiyan transformation, or can anyone get it?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimate Gohan is a transformation achieved by Son Gohan after Elder Kaiōshin unlocked his potential. Despite appearing to be in his normal state, Gohan, in actuality, is using the power of Super Saiyan 2 without the burden the latter transformation places on his body. As a result, Gohan is able to achieve a power beyond Super Saiyan 2 and even Super Saiyan 3, ultimately being even with Super Saiyan Blue ***after constant training***.

Comment: That's cool, but that isnt Gohan's last transformation.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a super saiyan transformation.

It is more of "Next" transformation of Ultimate Mystic Gohan .